# For loop on Pandas returns NaN for all value when trying to subtract two values?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, knn

I'm trying to calculate k-3 nearest neighbours by hand using the manhattan distance.

I have a data frame called `data` and a query observation called `query`. I need to be able to do something like this `sum(abs(query-data))` for every observation in `data`.

So far I have written a for loop like this:

```
 numeric_columns = data.columns[data.dtypes == np.number]

for rows in data:
    print(query[numeric_columns] - data[numeric_columns])
```

This returns all columns names with values as NaN for the original length of `data`: 16, 16 times over.
I'm quite new to writing for loops and I don't really understand what I've done wrong here. I also want to be able to return the distance and the index, but think I should attempt to get this for loop correct first.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `sub` that is used to subtract data frames. You can learn more here [NaNs when subtracting dataframes pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654802/nans-when-subtracting-dataframes-pandas[link]) and here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html.
Whats about the loop. You want only numeric columns to be subtracted, so you need an `if` checking that.
Then loop should look like this:

```
for rows in data:
    if data[rows].dtypes == np.number:
        t = query[row].sub(data[row], fill_value=0)
        print(t)
```

With a loop like that you don't need this part `numeric_columns = data.columns[data.dtypes == np.number]`